# addeventlistener doesnt run function

Tags: javascript, html

Everything works fine except the part with the id "spiel". There should have been a simlpe Number game where you need to guess a random generated number between 1 and 1000. It also helps you by saying if your input was to small or big (groß und klein). You have 10 tries to guess the number or you lose.

But nothing happens when I put some number in and press Enter button.

Before this it was giving

> "TypeError: guess is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"

So I removed the `onclick` because I already have `addeventlistener`.

But this time it doesn't give any errors and just doesn't work.

(I would normally just send the part with the game i am not sure if there is any other reasons for this.)

```js
  randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1001);
  tries = 10;
  
  function guess(){
    tries--;
  
    if (document.getElementById("input").value == randomnum) {
        document.getElementById("input").select();
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Gut";
    }
    if (document.getElementById("input").value < randomnum) {
        document.getElementById("input").select();
        document.getElementById("help").innerHTML = "Zu Klein";
    }
    if (document.getElementById("input").value > randomnum) {
        document.getElementById("input").select();
        document.getElementById("help").innerHTML = "Zu Groß";
    }
    if (tries == 0) {
        document.getElementById("input").select();
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Du hast keine versucher mehr";
    }
}
document.getElementById("guess").addEventListener("click", guess());
```

```css
*{
  font-family: 'Chau Philomene One', sans-serif;
}
.leiste {
  background-color: #EBBA0E;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.leistelist li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
.leistelist {
  float: right;
}
.letzt {
  margin: 0px 30px 0px 0px;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.mainns {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
footer section {
  border: 5px solid #2BFAB2;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 50px 50px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
footer section Input {
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-color: #0CF72C;
}
footer section p {
  color: #1DDE0B;
  margin-block-end: 5px;
  margin-block-start: 0px;
}
#infowebsite {
  text-align: center;
  color: beige;
  background-image: url("log5far.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 250px;
}
#infowebsite h1 {
  font-size: 64px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#infowebsite h2 {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 0px;
}
main div table tbody tr th img {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#infoich {
  background-color: #EB6E38;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 69px;
}
#infoich h2 {
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  color: #38EBD3;
  font-size: 36px;
}
#infoich p {
  color: #38EBD3;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#bilder {
  background-color: dimgray;
}
#bilder h2 {
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  padding: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 52px;
  color: cornsilk;
}
.Logo {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 25px;
}
.inputtext {
  padding: 5px 900px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
}
#kontakt h2 {
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  margin-block-end: 0px;
}
#ap {
  text-align: center;
  
}
#kontakt {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
footer {
  background-color: rgb(166, 212, 253);
}
#spiel {
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
}
#spiel h2 {
  margin-block-end: 0px;
  margin-block-start: 0px;
}
footer hr {
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  margin-block-end: 0px;
  border: darkmagenta solid 1px;
}
#ap :hover {
  color: wheat;
}
.leistelist li :hover {
  color: wheat;
}
#result {
  margin-block-end: 0px;
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <title>Renders</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Chau+Philomene+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="leiste">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank"><img src="phot.png" alt="Logo" height="50px" class="Logo"></a>
        <ul class="leistelist">
          <li><a href="#infowebsite">Start</a></li>
          <li><a href="#infoich">Über Mich</a></li>
          <li><a href="#bilder">Galerie</a></li>
          <li><a href="#spiel">Spiel</a></li>
          <li class="letzt"><a href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section id="infowebsite">
          <h1>Blender Renders</h1>
          <h2>von John Josh</h2>
        </section>
      <div class="mainns">
        <section id="infoich">
          <h2>Über Mich</h2>
            <p>Über mich gibts nichts viel.</p>
            <p>Ich habe diese Website gestaltet um html und css zu lernen sowie auch meine 3D arbeit vorzustellen.</p>
        </section>
        <section id="bilder">
          <h2>Galerie</h2>
          <div>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th><img src="Donut_gut.png" alt="Donut" height="250px"></th>
                  <th><img src="chess pic.png" alt="Schach" height="250px"></th>
                  <th><img src="table.png" alt="tisch" height=" 250px"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th><img src="Rendered_Baseballschlager.png" alt="Baseballschlager" height="250px"></th>
                  <th><img src="q2.png" alt="Auto Carpet" height="250px"></th>
                  <th><img src="gülfogy.png" alt="blume" height="250px"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th><img src="var10.png" alt="hintergrund" height="250px"></th>
                  <th><img src="nomatbar.png" alt="Teeglass" height="250px"></th>
                  <th><img src="eeeee.png" alt="eee?" height=" 250px"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th><img src="var1.jpeg" alt="1" height="250px"></th>
                  <th><img src="var2.jpeg" alt="2" height="250px"></th>
                  <th><img src="var3.jpeg" alt="3" height="250px"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th><img src="var4.jpeg" alt="4" height="250px"></th>
                  <th><img src="var5.jpeg" alt="5" height="250px"></th>
                  <th><img src="var6.jpeg" alt="6" height="250px"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th><img src="lava 3.png" alt="lava" width="444.656"></th>
                  <th><img src="Potio4.png" alt="pot" width="444.656"></th>
                  <th><img src="pory2.png" alt="poy" width="444.656"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <hr>
                    <p id="ap"><a href="AnderePhotos.html" target="_blank">Für andere Phtotos drücken sie Hier.</a></p>
                  <hr>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section id="spiel">
          <h2>Ein kleine Zahl Spiel</h2>

          <p> Rechner wird ein zahl zwischen 1 und 1000 wahlen.
          Als spieler muss raten welche zahl es ist.
          Schreib deine antworten in unten gegebene feld.</p>

          <p id="help"></p>
          <input type="text" id="input" maxlength="4">
          <button type="button" id="guess">Enter</button>
          <p id="result"></p>
          
        </section>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <hr>
      <section id="kontakt">
        <h2>Kontakt</h2>
        <p>Kontaktieren sie uns durch unten gegebene formular (zu zeit funktiniert es nicht).</p>
        <form action="" method="get">
          <Input type="email" name="nutzername" placeholder="Gmail/Email">
          <Input type="password" name="schlüssel" placeholder="Password">
          <Input type="submit" name="button">
          <textarea cols="8" rows="5" type="textarea" class="inputtext" name="etext">
        </form>
      </section>
      </form>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("guess").addEventListener("click", guess);` Don't use the parenthesis here or it'll be called when it loads, meaning before the event is called.

Comment: so.. i deleted      document.getElementById("guess").addEventListener("click", guess());    
and added    document.getElementById("guess").addEventListener("click", guess);      instead but it seems like it still doesnt give any out put to console or display anything.

Comment: @Nokta You don't need to delete the whole line, compare your code with the answer.

In your code, when you initialize an event handler, you call the function that you want to be called while the event is being processed. It doesn't have to be that way. Pass an [anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#the_function_expression_function_expression) that will call `guess` or just pass `guess`

Comment: @Nokta nothing happens because your snippet doesn't run the js code

Comment: i transferd the whole javascript code to html with with <script>...</script> and that worked. 
Could be the reason that it didnt work because i didnt linked them or does it have something to do with event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a function, but you are passing the result of a function call

Try:

```js
document.getElementById("guess").addEventListener("click", guess);
```